# How to pass a parameter to Vue @click event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a table using Vue.js and I want to define an `onClick` event for each row that passes `contactID`. Here is the code:

```
<tr v-for="item in items" class="static" 
    v-bind:class="{'evenRow': item.oddeven=='1', 'oddRow': item.oddeven=='0' }"
@click="addToCount('{item.contactID}')"
>
    <td>{{item.contactName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.recipient}}</td>
</tr>
```

On clicking a row, it is calling `addToCount()`, which is working. I want to pass `item.contactID` to `addToCount()`. Could someone suggest the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

When you are using Vue directives, the expressions are evaluated in the context of Vue, so you don't need to wrap things in `{}`.

`@click` is just shorthand for `v-on:click` directive so the same rules apply.

In your case, simply use `@click="addToCount(item.contactID)"`

Comment: What if the argument I want to pass is not iterated through and keyable but rather hard coded as such `<a href="#" @click="switchRoom" class="rooms">Interview Room</a>
        <a href="#" @click="switchRoom" class="rooms">Green Room</a>
        <a href="#" @click="switchRoom" class="rooms">Bavarian Caviar Room</a>
        <a href="#" @click="switchRoom" class="rooms">Sky Room</a>`

and I wanted to use the text content of the a elements in the switchRoom method?

Comment: @AkinHwan If it's already hard coded, just send the text as a parameter `@click="switchRoom('Sky Room')"`

Comment: What if it is not owned by the vue instance. For example you want to over-ride a chart click through and the chart sits in a vue directive but is not itself vue. You need to call the underlying click event somehow from the override vue click function?

Answer (score 234):

Just use a normal Javascript expression, no `{}` or anything necessary:

```
@click="addToCount(item.contactID)"
```

if you also need the event object:

```
@click="addToCount(item.contactID, $event)"
```

Comment: That second example with `$event` came in handy, glad you included it. I should've looked at the Vue Docs first, but here's where it's mentioned (in case anyone wants to see): 
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and here is how I manage to pass through:

In your case you have `addToCount()` which is called. now to pass down a param when user clicks, you can say `@click="addToCount(item.contactID)"`

in your function implementation you can receive the params like:

```
addToCount(paramContactID){
 // the paramContactID contains the value you passed into the function when you called it
 // you can do what you want to do with the paramContactID in here!

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is similar to that already provided by @Linus