# How do I pass input text using v-on:change to my vue method?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6

How can I pass the input value from my html to my vue method called checkEx
ist() ? I would like to retrieve that value within my checkExist() method. Could any advice how I can do this? I am still new to vue.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" v-model="form.email" v-validate="'required|email'"  v-on:change="checkExist">
```

**VUE ELEMENT:**

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
       checkExist:function(){
       }
  }
})
```

Comment: The `input` element's `v-model` should be accessible from anywhere in your component, so you can check `this.form.email` in the `checkExist` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529516/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-vue-click

Comment: sounds like `@change="checkExist($event)"` or `@input="checkExist($event)"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you need to define `form:{email:"", ...}` in the `data` as well.
Pass $event inside `checkExist()` .
Something like this,

```js
function callMe() {
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
     form:{email:""},
     email:""
    },
    methods: {
       checkExist(event){

         this.email=event.target.value;

       } 
    
    }

  })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
 
 <input type="text" @input="checkExist($event)" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" v-model="form.email">
<p>email:  {{email}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

The v-model should already bind that input event.

But you can pass the event to v-on:change like this:

```
v-on:change="event => checkExist(event)"
```

Check exist would need to accept the event as a parameter.
The value of the input will now be accessible inside the vue function via *event.target.value*.

```
checkExist: function(event){
    let value = event.target.value
}
```

Comment: I get the following error.
ReferenceError: checkExist is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Simpler even more, you don't need to pass the entire event to your handler function.

```
@change="checkExist($event.target.value)"
```

.

```
checkExist: function(value){
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do it in ES6 syntax without using 'v-model' as below

```
<input v-on:change="(event) => inputValue = event.target.value" :value="inputValue" type="text"/>
```